# Not able to send key using AutoItX with java

Tags: autoit

I am new to AutoIT. I can access and use the AutoItX in java. But now I am facing problem that I am not able to send the key, The sendkey parameter is not considered as key, instead it is considering as text

e.g in my code x.send("{ALT}n");

In this case key is not getting pressed instead the text {ALT}n is displaying in notepad Please suggest. Thanks for your help in advance.

Rupali

Comment: I've got no experience of AutoItX with Java, but it is possible you have to specify the flags parameter for send explicitly, so try `x.send("{ALT}n", 0)`. After that, I'd try sending `"!n"` and seeing if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx. that worked for me.
Also we can use 
x.controlSend("Window Title","text","","{ENTER}",false);